# Undo functionality in an MVC design

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a C++ application designed according to a classic [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). The model is modified through a controller interface by an external source by means of a [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). The commands are represented by an Action object (and its derivatives).

Now I want to be able to undo the modifications, but my problem is that I have no getters in my controller, only setters. This seems quite logical, since there's no reason someone should be able to get info about the model through the controller. Thus, I can't have my Action objects store the state of the Model, since they have no access to it.

How would one solve this? I'd like to keep my application *as extendable as possible* and I'm not quite sure which option is the best for that. The methods I though up so far are:

1. Putting getter methods in the controller. This seems to go against the MVC pattern.
2. Giving the Action a pointer to a View. The Action could then either:

   1. Use individual getters to get the state of specific elements of the model to be modified.
   2. Use a [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) method implemented by the Viewer.

Maybe there's an even better way to do this? Right now, to be the best option seems to be 2, suboption 1 (with suboption 2, I'd quite possible store a lot more state than necessary to undo one action).

*Note:* I know there's other questions on how to implement an undo action. However, the only answers I found gave suggestions to use a Command or Memento pattern. I know this is most probably the way to go. What I'm asking for is how to integrate this as cleanly & extendable as possible in an MVC design.

**[Edit]** What I don't like about the Memento pattern is that it forces me to store a complete state. Let's say my model is a 1000x1000 matrix and my Command is ChangeOneValueAtLocation. To be able to undo its changes, the ChangeOneValueAtLocation object only needs to store the previous value of the location it's changing, but that doesn't seem possible with Memento. The larger my model, the biggest this problem becomes.

**[Edit 2]** Another problem I have with Memento in the specific case of this application: for every method a Command object can execute on the Model, there's a method that does exact opposite (or can easily be coaxed to do so). This is why I would find it a waste to have to store the whole state, there should be no need to, reverting a single Command is very straightforward, the only problem is getting the data to be able to do it.

Also, I don't need to be able to undo a specific Command, only the topmost one on my history stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also support the model layer containing undo support. There are quite a few ways to handle this in the model side. The first and most obvious is the models themselves remembering the history of the changes with "labels", but this is probably going to be difficult to synchronize for all your model classes.

One other option is to create a history manager that has a concept of a "transaction", which causes it to generate an undo point, and take a snapshot of your models, or start recording changes (for reduced memory usage), or record commands that cause model changes, etc.The models notify the manager on change, and finally you complete the transaction (or not, because the next start of transaction can be the end of the previous one). Once you add in the ability to rollback to a certain point, the work will be done. By making things slightly more complicated in this manager class, you can create an undo tree (like the one in emacs), so it is also quite a flexible way to approach it.

The above solution is not quite in the model layer, though. It is a support class that is driven by both the model and the controller. If you remove the transaction concept, then it is completely model-driven, but implementing the concept of an undo operation might be somewhat tricky. If you change it to act as a command proxy, it is the only entity used by your controllers, and is clearly a model. It is too rough a design at this point to choose one approach over another, but I am leaning towards the "transaction" model. It feels easy enough to implement.

Comment: I decided to go with this approach, since it lets me transfer models and their associated history easily to off-site clients. Putting the history in a controller would make this more difficult. Furthermore, I have a single front-end class for my model, so I don't think the non-atomic undo problem ``sehe`` mentions will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd really recommend building the undo tree into your Controller

Building it into the model could run you into trouble:

- the 'model' is usually fragmented per view (each view has it's own partial model)
- this will lead to non-atomic undo (undoing *part* of an operation due to the view not knowing what other things (models) would have to be undone etc)

The controller is the 'action dispatcher', so it'd have to say

1. clone state (all models) snapshot
2. add action to history with reference to snapshot
3. run action

then undo would be

1. pop action off history stack (optionally push to 'future' stack)
2. restore snapshot
3. display view

Also, make undo work with highlevel actions (see Composite Pattern or Command Pattern)

Comment: But now the question is still: how do I implement this cleanly? How does my Command class get its snapshot? From a View implementing a Memento pattern, thus needing a pointer to a View? From a getter in the Controller it's operating on, thus breaking the MVC pattern?

Comment: The controller _is_ responsible for the state. So, making the controller remember state, is NOT breaking the MVC pattern. However, there should _not_ be a need to expose it. You can do Controller.Rollback() - controller can optionally delegate the actual implementation to the Model (if it does implement Memento, e.g.)

Comment: The thing is I want to get the state into my Command object. So ``Controller.rollback()`` could just pop the last Command off the stack and call ``undo()`` on it. I guess I could have Controller put the state into the Command before calling ``execute()`` on it. I don't like the idea of saving complete state though (see edit in my original question for more info).

Comment: Darhuuk: sounds like a good concept to me, as long as the commands don't get shuffled. It will be harder to verify correctness of rollback if you don't save full state though. The balance is up to you

Answer (score 0):

Build the undo functionality in your model itself. Let you model keep a list of commands. Run the commands in the reverse order when your view passes an undo signal to the model.